# why isn't require_once working with my path names

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing a plugin, and near the top of the main plugin file I have a series of `require_once` statements as is typical.

After *more than ten hours* of trying to figure out why WP couldn't find my classes, I finally landed on this -- if I had:

```
require_once( 'includes/myclassfile.php' );
```

it failed.  But if I explicitly put in the base path like so:

```
define ( 'MY_DIR', rtrim( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ), '/' ) );
require_once( MY_DIR . '/includes/myclassfile.php' );
```

it worked.

So my question is: why didn't the first form work?  My IDE (PhpStorm) understood it, the boilerplate I started from used it, and I have other plugins installed that use that form, and they work.  What could have been different about this case?

*Edit*: This question got marked as duplicate of another that also addressed confusion about the proper use of `require`, however in that case, the final conclusion was the opposite of what worked for me.  I am not asking what to do, but *why* one version would fail.  Isaac's answer suggests a reason, but it is unsatisfying since there are other top-level plugins in my wordpress install that do work with the form that doesn't work for mine --- I would like to know what makes mine different.

(Just to be complete, here is the full plugin file:)

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: A Strenga Projects
 * Version: 1.0
 * Description: Projects for Strenga
 * Author: DD
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

define ( 'STRENGA_PROJECTS_DIR', rtrim( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ), '/' ) );    
require_once( STRENGA_PROJECTS_DIR . '/includes/plugin.php' );

function myFoofunction() {
    ladeda();  // defined in plugin.php
}
myFoofunction();
```

Comment: Long story short - always use an absolute filepath. PHP's include/require path resolution is [confusing to say the least](http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/). If there was a file `includes/plugins.php` at some point in your [includes path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) (perhaps `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`?), that file would've have been included instead.

Comment: Don't mess with __FILE__ when __DIR__ will get you there faster. Also 'rtrim' is similar to 'untrailingslashit'.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic --- this is exactly the answer I was looking for --- thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths can be confusing in complex applications like WordPress. Plugin files themselves are **included** by the scripts that call them, and so relative locations within [will be interpreted as those of the file that called them](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

It's always best practice to provide a full path using a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) such as `__FILE__` or `__DIR__`, as you've discovered.